# How to use model CRUD properly?

Tags: php, mysql, fuelphp

I have one database table `images` and second one `objects`. `images` table is having `object_id` primary key related to `objects`.`id` field.

Now after a POST I am selecting images by posted ID's, loop through results and select appropriate objects by primary key:

```
// 1 query
$images = Model_Image::find(array('where' => array('approved' => 0, array('object_id', 'in', Input::post('objects'))));

foreach($images as $image)
{
    // now get it's object
    // 2 queries
    $obj = Model_Object::find_by_pk($image->object_id);
    $obj->image = 1;
    // 3 queries
    $obj->save();
}
```

The thing is, I'm wondering, how should I work this out properly - I think using CRUD is not always a good idea and might affect performance even though it looks pretty and feels good to use it. But is it really worth to sacrifice performance? Lets say, we have 10 images to edit, so that would generate **11 queries** to perform a simple action.

I mean, I could simply use the following query to do it all...

```
UPDATE `objects` SET `image` = 1
LEFT JOIN `images` ON(`image`.`object_id` = `object.id`)
WHERE `images`.`approved` = 0 AND `images`.`id` IN ([post ids]);
```

So is it worth to still use CRUD in this case?

Comment: What do you mean by _"using CRUD"_? CRUD is only an ancronym for Create Read Update Delete and doesn't enforce any specific way on you about _how_ you should actually do your DB calls.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson See the Fuel's CRUD model / ORM Crud: https://fuelphp.com/docs/classes/model_crud/introduction.html

Comment: Ok. To avoid confusion, I suggest that you add that you're using Fuel PHP's CRUD-model to your question.

Comment: Sounds like you're confusing `CRUD` with an `ORM`...? The code you provide uses fuels ORM.

Comment: @Stuart It's CRUD. ORM uses CRUD as well.

Comment: CRUD is an idea, he is using fuels ORM to `C`reate, `R`ead, `U`pdate, and `D`elete.

Comment: CRUD is an idea used either by ORM and Model_Crud and that's what I am describing. Both share a similar functionality.

Comment: Correct. Model_Crud provides very light-weight functionality for those who don't need the full ORM. 
The question however isn't related to that, but whether or not the overhead of an abstraction layer is worth it. And the answer to that isn't really a technical one.